# Asynchronous Process accessing same file at one time

Tags: powershell

I am facing issue with Asynchronous process.Before any process to execute it will copy the ABC file from X location to  Y location, once its done with process then it will delete the file from Y location.  When multiple process run at same time, some of the process is failing while deleting the file because of that file doesn't exist at Y location. Can one of you help me out how to handle this type of Scenario using Powershell & I am  new to Powershell Scripting.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to visit the help center and also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so you can learn what types of questions are accepted here, how to write questions, and how to use this site effectively

Comment: You can simply use error action preferences, but go through the documentation. [PS Error Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/powershell/8075/error-handling#t=201702100854266945478)